# Gatsby Error ReferenceError: React is not defined when migrating from JSX to Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project which I want to migrate from JSX to Typescript. I am following this [guide](https://medium.com/maxime-heckel/getting-started-with-typescript-on-gatsby-8544b47c1d27) to achieve this.

Configurations for Typescript are as follows:

`tslint.json`:

```
{
    "rulesDirectory": "tslint-plugin-prettier",
    "extends": ["tslint:latest", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier": true,
        "jsx-no-multiline-js": false,
        "jsx-no-lambda": false,
        "import-name": false,
        "no-boolean-literal-compare": false
    }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./built",
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
...
"type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
"lint": "tslint --project ."
...
```

`gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        'gatsby-plugin-tslint', // TSLint
        // TS Plugin. Gatsby already ships with TS
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
            options: {
              isTSX: true, // defaults to false
              jsxPragma: 'jsx', // defaults to "React"
              allExtensions: true, // defaults to false
            },
        }
    ]
};
```

I am getting the following error when I run `gatsby develop`:

```
error There was an error compiling the html.js component for the development server.

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help https://gatsby.dev/debug-html ReferenceError: React is not defined

  18 |             next: function (result) {
  19 |                 if (_this.lastError || _this.isDifferentFromLastResult(result)) {
> 20 |                     _this.updateLastResult(result);
     | ^
  21 |                     iterateObserversSafely(_this.observers, 'next', result);
  22 |                 }
  23 |             },


  WebpackError: ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

I am using React import in ES5 format as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```